# Identification of Integrated Circuit or Chipset component

Tags: identification

I am attempting to identify the purpose, manufacturer, and any other information about this component which was acquired from an obsolete electronics repair store.

[image: component]
[image: component2]

As far as I can tell, the markings are "8A24, HT47, 36" Though there may be a 1 before the H, I can't quite tell. I'm not sure which of these would comprise the part number, or if they are even useful at all.

I've done Google searches for the sensible combinations of these codes, but didn't yield anything similar.

Comment: This is a application specific thin film circuit. Could be anything. From the high pin SMD component with the crystal on top most likely a µC module from some car engine control unit. Those were made in huge numbers and may pop up anywhere.

Comment: Take a picture of it, centered, on a white background.  Then do a reverse google image search.  Maybe you'll get lucky.   I would just throw it away personally....